# Can Google Code source changes be shown on my website?

Tags: google-code

I use GoogleCode for my open source project. I'd really like to have the latest commit messages shown on my website in some sort of feed.

Is this possible? Are there any tools out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's quite simple.

The Project Feeds page has plenty of info, "Source Changes" is the one I wanted.

http://code.google.com/p/rokon/feeds